# Navigation bar reappears on the welcome screen. How to hide it permanently?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I am working on an app for iPad. Here is the flow:

Welcome Screen -> Home screen -> then home screen navigates to rest of the screens.

I have made the navigation bar hidden in the welcome screen. But it is available on rest of the screens. On home screen, the navigation bar has a button which takes user back to the welcome screen. When user presses that button and goes back to the welcome screen, the navigation bar appears on the welcome screen. When app is launched there is no navigation bar on welcome screen, but while the app is running and the user goes back to the welcome screen, navigation bar appears. I want to permanently hide it from the welcome screen. I don't want it to appear on the welcome screen at any stage. In the viewDidLoad of welcome screen, the navigation bar is hidden. Then why it appears when user goes to the welcome screen while the app is running?
How can I remove it??

any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks and regards
PC

Comment: There is a possibility that the other views are turning it back to visible. You will need to turn it back off when your view becomes visible again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution here may be to put `self.navigationBar.hidden = YES;` in the `-viewWillAppear:` method of the `UIViewController` where you wish to have the bar perpetually hidden.